# How to avoid step into built-in functions when debugging in PyCharm?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

For example:

```py
df = load_dataset(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(dataset), "aclImdb"))
```

I don't want to debug `dirname` and `join`, since they are Python built-in functions, but only want to debug user defined functions like `load_dataset`.

Is there a way to control that in PyCharm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to stop the debugger from stepping into library functions when you press [Step into](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/stepping-through-the-program.html#step-into) <kbd>F7</kbd> bu going to `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Build, Execution, Deployment` `>` `Debugger` `>` `Stepping` `>` `Python` and checking the option `Do not step into library scripts`.

(One alternative could also be using [Step into my code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/stepping-through-the-program.html#step-into-my-code) <kbd>Alt + Shift + F7</kbd>).

As shown in the screenshot.

[image]

The following is a code example using only standard library that can be copied for testing

```py
import os


def my_function():
    return 2


my_str = str(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), str(my_function())))
```

This screenshot shows using `Step into` <kbd>F7</kbd> having `Do not step into library scripts` unchecked and `Always do smart step into` checked.

[image]

Notice the 3 setting options are interconnected, if you choose `Do not step into library scripts` together with `Always do smart step into` the IDE will still give you a choice to step into the library function. If you uncheck the later option the above example will automatically step into your function.